# How does $r$ for univariate regression relate to the general definition of $R^2$?

Tags: regression, least-squares, correlation

We know that the correlation coefficient in a univariate regression case between $x$ and $y$ is

$$r = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x - \bar{x})^2\sum_{i=1}^n (y - \bar{y})^2}} \\
r^2 = \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x - \bar{x})^2\sum_{i=1}^n (y - \bar{y})^2}} \right)^2
$$

The general definition for $R^2$ is
\begin{align}
    R^2 = 1 - \frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}} \\
    SS_{res} = \sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 \\
    SS_{tot} = \sum_i (y_i-\bar{y})^2 \\ \\
    SS_{reg} = \sum_i (\hat{y_i}-\bar{y})^2 \\ \\
\end{align}

In the univariate regression form, $r^2$ isn't a function of the $\hat{y}$, and the latter $R^2$ isn't a function of $x$. How is $r^2 = R^2$?

Comment: Hint: use the definition $\hat{y}_i=\alpha +\beta x_i$. What are the OLS estimates for $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum( x_i - \bar{x} )( y_i - \bar{y} ) }{ \sum (x_i - \bar{x} ) ^2}.
$$
Since $SSreg = \hat{\beta} ^ 2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x} ) ^2$,

\begin{align}
R ^ 2 &= \frac{SSreg}{SST}\\
& = \frac{\hat{\beta}^2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x} ) ^2}{\sum ( y _i - \bar{y})^2}\\
& = \frac{ \left( \sum( x_i - \bar{x} )( y_i - \bar{y}   )\right)^2 }{\sum ( y_i - \bar{y} ) ^2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x} ) ^2}\\
& = r^2.
\end{align}